# Accessing ENV VARS during docker build

Tags: docker, npm, docker-compose, font-awesome

I have been looking for a proper solution where I can access environmental variables in my docker build. I am aware that I can pass buildArgs but that would mean that I have to provide the ENV VAR as a build Argument which is not an option in our case.

Below you can find the snippet of my docker compose file (some volume mounts are removed on purpose for this post):

```
services:
  client-dev:
    build:
      dockerfile: dev.Dockerfile
      args:
        - ENV_FILE=.env
    ports:
      - '5173:5173'
```

and this is my dev.Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:18

ARG ENV_FILE
COPY $ENV_FILE .env

# Load environment variables from .env using a shell command
RUN export $(cat .env | xargs)
RUN npm config set "@fortawesome:registry" https://npm.fontawesome.com/
RUN npm config set "//npm.fontawesome.com/:_authToken" $FONTAWESOME_NPM_AUTH_TOKEN

WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app/package.json

EXPOSE 5173

RUN npm i

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

As you can see I'm trying to achieve the use of ENV VAR in my docker build by loading a .env file and exporting them in a shell command. However the `$FONTAWESOME_NPM_AUTH_TOKEN` var that is called still seems to be empty. Since it is not possible to provide a .env file as part of the docker build, I was wondering if there is a better way of approaching this.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are facing is related to the fact that environment variables set using `export` during the build process are not persistently available in subsequent layers of the Docker image. Therefore, when you try to use `$FONTAWESOME_NPM_AUTH_TOKEN` in the later part of your Dockerfile, it doesn't retain the value set in the earlier layers.

To handle environment variables during the build process in a Dockerfile, you can use the `ARG` instruction for build-time variables and the ENV instruction for environment variables that are available in the running container. However, note that build-time variables are not accessible in the running container.

Here's a modified version of your Dockerfile that uses ARG for the build-time variable:

```
FROM node:18

ARG ENV_FILE
ARG FONTAWESOME_NPM_AUTH_TOKEN

COPY $ENV_FILE .env

# Load environment variables from .env using a shell command
RUN export $(cat .env | xargs) && \
    npm config set "@fortawesome:registry" https://npm.fontawesome.com/ && \
    npm config set "//npm.fontawesome.com/:_authToken" $FONTAWESOME_NPM_AUTH_TOKEN

WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app/package.json

EXPOSE 5173

RUN npm i

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

Your original Dockerfile attempted to use export to set environment variables during the build process. However, the issue with this approach is that environment variables set using export are not persistently available in subsequent layers of the Docker image. The environment variables set during the build process are only available during that particular build step and do not carry over to the next steps.

In the modified Dockerfile I provided, I used the `ARG` instruction for build-time variables and `ENV` for environment variables that are available in the running container. This allows you to pass build-time arguments during the build process and use them in the specific build.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi, yeah it helps but that would mean that I still have to pass it now as build arg which I am trying to avoid. But it currently looks as the only solution that will work